# Rails Displaying Recommendations - Facebook/Linkedin style

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, user-interface

I'm writing a `Rails 3.2.1` app and I would like to display suggested items to a user in the following way:

Currently, I have an array of suggested items, and I want to display 5 suggestions at a time.  I would like the user to be able to

1. click on the item to link to something.
2. click on the close button (and "X") to
3. if the user rejects the recommendation by clicking on the close button, we display

another suggestion in the same place on the list of 5 displayed suggestions. So the a new suggestion takes the place of the rejected one.

Any ideas on how I can do it?  I have tried searching on the web but I can't seem to find a useful direction. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could 'store' the decision of the user in session/cookie/database depending on how persistent you want the decision to be.
After the user rejects a suggestion you could just reload the suggestions taking the decision into account.

E.g.

```
Suggestions.where(["id NOT IN (?)", User.rejected_suggestions])
```

(Assuming you have an m-to-n-relation between User and Suggestions called rejected_suggestions)

And the way it is displayed is just javascript.
You could use for example jQuery and fade the rejected suggestion into hiding and let the new one slide in.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

And for reloading and storing the decision just use an ajax call.

**Alternatively:**
Load a few more suggestions (than 5) and only use JS to fade them out and slide new ones into the view - and when all suggestions have been rejected just display something like: 'We are sorry, there are no suggestions for you at the moment.'